# Create pyramids using javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to create two pyramids using for loop in JavaScript and print it in the console as given below:

[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Should it be in two divs, a table, or?

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (var i = 4; i >= 1; i = i - 1) {
  for (var j = 4; j >= i; j = j - 1) {
    document.write(j);
  }
  //i want this to print a new line
  document.write("<br>");
}
```

Comment: For first triangle try this code

Comment: For your second trianle output take third variable c=1 before loop initialisation and print with (print c) and c++